# BroadcastReceiver trying to return result during a non-ordered broadcast

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

In my app broadcast receiver error is cause. i am creating google cloud messaging demo

my LogCat is

```
06-03 15:09:37.584: E/BroadcastReceiver(15498): BroadcastReceiver trying to return result during a non-ordered broadcast
06-03 15:09:37.584: E/BroadcastReceiver(15498): java.lang.RuntimeException: BroadcastReceiver trying to return result during a non-ordered broadcast
06-03 15:09:37.584: E/BroadcastReceiver(15498):     at android.content.BroadcastReceiver.checkSynchronousHint(BroadcastReceiver.java:783)
06-03 15:09:37.584: E/BroadcastReceiver(15498):     at android.content.BroadcastReceiver.setResult(BroadcastReceiver.java:658)
06-03 15:09:37.584: E/BroadcastReceiver(15498):     at com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver.onReceive(GCMBroadcastReceiver.java:56)
06-03 15:09:37.584: E/BroadcastReceiver(15498):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2609)
06-03 15:09:37.584: E/BroadcastReceiver(15498):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:151)
06-03 15:09:37.584: E/BroadcastReceiver(15498):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1380)
06-03 15:09:37.584: E/BroadcastReceiver(15498):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
```

This is Broadcast Receiver

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mHandleMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            String newMessage = intent.getExtras().getString(Config.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
            String newName = intent.getExtras().getString("name");
            String newIMEI = intent.getExtras().getString("imei");

            Log.i("GCMBroadcast","Broadcast called."+newIMEI);

            // Waking up mobile if it is sleeping
            aController.acquireWakeLock(getApplicationContext());

            String msg = lblMessage.getText().toString();
            msg = newName+" : "+newMessage+"\n"+msg;
            // Display message on the screen
            lblMessage.setText(msg);
            //lblMessage.append("\n"+newName+" : "+newMessage);         


            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                    "Got Message: " + newMessage, 
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            /************************************/
             //CustomListViewValuesArr.clear();
             int rowCount = DBAdapter.validateNewMessageUserData(newIMEI);
             Log.i("GCMBroadcast", "rowCount:"+rowCount);
             if(rowCount <= 1 ){
                    final UserData schedSpinner = new UserData();

                    /******* Firstly take data in model object ********/
                    schedSpinner.setName(newName);
                    schedSpinner.setIMEI(newIMEI);


                  /******** Take Model Object in ArrayList **********/
                  CustomListViewValuesArr.add(schedSpinner);
                  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }

                //CustomListViewValuesArr.addAll(SpinnerUserData);



            /************************************/

            // Releasing wake lock
            aController.releaseWakeLock();
        }
    };
```

Please tell me how can i resolve error i am try to find out on internet but exact can,t find solution.

Comment: I am on the same issue, can you please point the line at which the exception occurs. May be together we can find a fix.

Comment: hi I m having same problem ... can anyone please help us...

Answer (score 1):

To begin with I am not an expert in Android Development and especially in case of Broadcast receivers.

I went through the code you have posted here and my beginner brain could not find any statement that sets a result. I am unable to identify the statement where the exception hits you so my answer might be vague.

---

According to the `BroadcastReceiver` documentation running receivers in an asynchronous fashion is more efficient but means that recievers cannot use the result or abort APIs of the BroadcastReceiver class.

<strike>One solution to the problem is using `Context.sendOrderedBroadcast` but since we are dealing with GoogleCloudMessages we are not the liberty of handling the Broadcast Sending part.</strike>

Google Cloud Messaging broadcasts are ordered. It's just the broadcast received in this case is non-ordered.

There is a function `isOrderedBroadcast()` which can be used as a *workaround* so that you can avoid setting result to an non-ordered broadcast.